# Backup and restore db2 between instances and diferent owners

Tags: db2

I have two instances of db2 express-c. On one of those instances I have a database onto which I created a schema with tables and stored procedures and other stuff.

I've created a backup of that DB and restored it onto the other instance that I had.

That other instance has db2inst2 as the owner, and I've transferred ownership of the schema to him, granted control on everything, granted privileges over the schema etc...

I've given execute to this user over the stored procedures, and I've given control over every package on the DB.

Right now I can create new procedures on this schema, but I can't replace a previously existing stored procedure.

Right now I tried to transfer ownership of the package that my SP uses and I got caught with a weird error:

the command I used was:

```
transfer ownership of package schema.P1001724249 to user db2inst2 preserve privileges;
```

And I got this error:

> Transferring ownership of "schema.P1001724249" failed because of a dependency involving "schema.SQL150203162243554". Reason code: "5".. SQLCODE=-20344

I'm getting out of ideas, has anyone ever did something close to this?

Comment: You didn't post the error. To `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE`, you must be the owner of the _procedure_, package has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I would believe so, so I did a command to transfer the ownership of the procedure from the old user to the new one, however despite the command running successfully, the owner of the SP seemed to remain the old user.